# pqxx::result::tuple has not been declared (PostgreSQL library for c++)

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I try to compile program, which uses pqxx (PostgreSQL lib for c++). One of my function prototypes, looks like this:

```
bool compare(pqxx::result::tuple row1, pqxx::result::tuple row2);
```

Compiler says for this line:

```
classes.h:64:38: error: 'pqxx::result::tuple' has not been declared
   bool compare(pqxx::result::tuple row1, pqxx::result::tuple row2);
```

I have no idea, why I get this error. I've included `pqxx` like this:

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
```

I use in other place `pqxx::result`, and it works. Why I cannot delare variable of type `pqxx::result::tuple` ?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the different documentations, `pqxx::result::tuple` existed in version 3.1 of the library (see [here](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/3.1/html/Reference/a00082.html)).

It then became `pqxx::tuple` in version 4.0 (see [here](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00107.html)), and it looks like it disapeared in latest development version (see [here](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/development/Reference/annotated.html), maybe it was droped for [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)).

So if you're using version 4.0, replace in your code `pqxx::result::tuple` with `pqxx::tuple`.

If you're using latest development version, try replacing in your code `pqxx::result::tuple` with `std::tuple`.

**EDIT:**

You found it yourself: in fact, `pqxx::tuple` was replaced by [`pqxx::row`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/development/Reference/a00081.html) in latest version.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the answer. Unfortunately, changing `pqxx::result::tuple`, for `std::tuple`, returns the same type of error from compiler. My version of pqxx is 5.0.1