# No pqxx::tuple in libpqxx library?

Tags: c++, postgresql, c++11, linker, libpqxx

I`ve got the newest ubuntu and I`ve done:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo apt-get install libpqxx-4.0v5
sudo apt-get install libpqxx-dev
```

I can`t compile program which uses pqxx::tuple.

Compilation:

```
g++ test.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ -lpqxx -lpq
or
g++ test.cpp -lpqxx -lpq -o test
```

Console output:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:15:21: error: ‘tuple’ in namespace ‘pqxx’ does not name a type
const pqxx::tuple row = r[rownum];
```

This is the problematic line:

```
const pqxx::tuple row = r[rownum];
```

When I remove this line, program works correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
int main()
{
  try {
    pqxx::connection c("dbname=mydb user=postgres port=5432 password=*** hostaddr=127.0.0.1");
    pqxx::work w(c);
    pqxx::result r = w.exec("SELECT * FROM get_player_data_function()");
    w.commit();
    const int num_rows = r.size();
    for (int rownum=0; rownum < num_rows; ++rownum) {
        const pqxx::tuple row = r[rownum];
    }
  }
  catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure... but if I understand correctly [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890712), you have to substitute `pqxx::tuple` with `pqxx::row`.

So, I suppose

```
const pqxx::row row = r[rownum];
```

Comment: output after change:                                                                                      /tmp/ccEpNRjn.o: In function `pqxx::result::operator[](unsigned long) const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK4pqxx6resultixEm[_ZNK4pqxx6resultixEm]+0x27): undefined reference to `pqxx::row::row(pqxx::result const*, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user3455638 - the preceding error was a compilation error; this one is a linking error; so I suppose you need link another library. But, sorry, I'm not an expert in `pqxx`

Comment: You`r right. At first, change pqxx::tuple to pqxx::row. Second, linker error. Compile with -L/usr/local/lib and/or -I/usr/local/include g++ test.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lpqxx -lpq. PQXXlib include and lib are located in /usr/local/* paths.